# Jquery envio de informacion a sql

Tags: php, jquery, sql

tenog un problema, estoy con un codigo en el cual envio datos a sql por php mediante jquery, eh puesto unos alert para ver la info que me manda, y es correcta, pero cuando lo inserta en la sql, me pone otra cosa.

```
var dpt_id = $('#dpt_id option:selected').html();   
alert(dpt_id);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando lo inserta en la SQL aparece esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo php que recibe los datos es:

```
$dpt=$_POST['dpt_id'];
```

y el insert pues un insert normal y corriente
$sql="INSERT into codigos (Fila,colum,dpt_d........

la estructura de la SQL, es un campo INT(11) sin mas, a alguien se le ocurre que puede pasar?

gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias

Al final lo logre, era una bobada, F12 Vaciar cache del navegador...

se habria quedado pillado de antes, no se jaja

Muchas gracias igualmente